# Find parametric equations of the line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 = c$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find parametric equations of the line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 = c$ for numbers $d_1, d_2$, and $c$ in $\Bbb{R}$, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not both zero.

I thought of 2 ways of solving it, but I got more than one answer, so wondering if my reasoning is correct.

Method 1:
We find 2 solutions to the equation $(0, {c \over d_2})$ and $({c \over d_1}, 0)$. Then we have

d$({c \over d_1}, {-c \over d_2}) + (0, {c \over d_2}) = (x_1, x_2)$.

$x_1 = d {c\over d_1}$

$x_2 = d{-c\over d_2} + {c\over d_2}$

Method 2:
First we find solutions to the homogeneous system $d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 = 0$, $(d_2, -d_1)$ and $(-d_2, d_1)$.

We also have a solution to the equation $d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 = c$, for example, $(0, {c\over d_2})$.

Thus we have $s(d_2, -d_1) + t(-d_2, d_1) + (0, {c\over d_2}) = (x_1, x_2)$.

$x_1 = sd_2 - td_2$

$x_2 = -sd_1 + td_1 + {c\over d_2}$.

Wondering if my reasoning is correct? If not, how to solve this problem?

Comment: You understand, don't you, that there exist infinitely many "parameterizations" for one line?  Given $d_1x_1+ d_2x_2= c$, and assuming that $d_2$ is not 0, $x_2= \frac{c- d_1x_1}{d_2}$ so one obvious parameterization is $x_1= t$, $x_2= \frac{c- d_1t}{d_2}$.

Comment: Call the two points in your method 1 $P_1$ and $P_2$. If you rearrange the resulting parameterization a bit, you can write it as $d P_1+(1-d) P_2$, which I find easier to remember. This form makes the geometric meaning a bit clearer, too, I think: for $0\le d\le 1$ this interpolates linearly between the two points (e.g., $d=1/2$ gives you the midpoint). This interpolation is then extended to a complete line.

Comment: This question requires $d_1$ or $d_2$ to be able to take the value of $0$. Similar methods can give you an answer which allows this, just not at those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea is to just check your work. For method 2:

$d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 = c$
$d_1 (sd_2 - td_2) + d_2 (-sd_1 + td_1 + {c\over d_2})  = c$
 
$s d_ 1 d_2 - t d_1 d_2   -s d_1 d_2 + t d_1 d_2 + c = c$

Yup - looks good (if $d_2 \ne 0$).

Also, you can verify that the the mapping you've defined,

$t \mapsto (sd_2 - td_2,-sd_1 + td_1 + {c\over d_2})$

is bijective from $\mathbb R$ onto a line in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

You can check method 1 on your own. But you need to choose a 'parametrization framework'
 ($d_1 \ne 0 \text{ OR } d_2 \ne 0$), so think about finding a method 2$^{'}$.